# Classification of algebras over GF(2)

Tags: ring-theory

I want to know something about algebras over GF(2). What are best structure theorem that a known at present? What I can read about this? Is there trivial excercise or it is not clear how make it now? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Getting this question out of unanswered-limbo*

---

Beyond "every $k$ algebra is a quotient of a free algebra $k\langle X\rangle$ where $X$ is some set of (possibly noncommuting) indeterminates" there is not much more to be said.  It doesn't matter if you are talking about $GF(2)$ or some other field: the question is equally broad.

Comment: Ghosts of the past. I agree with the answer.

Comment: @MykolaPochekai It's Halloween in my country, after all.